# How to use phasher to detect similar images in database?

Tags: php, image

I'm building a search image engine, so I need to detect similar / duplicated images in a database and I've found [phasher](https://github.com/kennethrapp/phasher).

This class helps me create hash strings for every image. I can easily compare two images, but now I want to search on a large database to find if a particular image has any clones or similar images?

How can I search with the image hash string?

Comment: Why not restrict the column in your database that you're storing the hashes in by using a unique column?  Then you can't have a duplicated image!

Comment: @Coulton i already had. i need to check similar picture before insert to DB. that's means: same picture but different size, crop, low quality , rotated .... that's right. sorry, my english is poor

Comment: From what I understand from reading about phasher and the further reading suggested on the linked page, this will calculate hashes that are “similar” for similar images. So you would have to use a function that can calculate the “similarity” of two such hashes, f.e. as a percent value — so you will need an adequate [string metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). But those are quite costly and usually have to compute the distance between two input values on-the-fly – so doing that on database level will be quite expensive.

Comment: @CBroe yep. phasher created hash string for each images. and compare them to find out how similar there is. But i want to search similar images in database, so i inserted all hash string to database but i didn't know how to query similar other hash string on database... i heard about hamming distance, but there's no much info about it with MySQL. If there's no way to do with mysql database, there is any solution to do a image search engine like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am building a tool looks like yours but search engine for Facebook profiles pictures I call it FBpp = "Facebook Profile Picture";

I didn't finish it yet it's something I build to sharpen my skills in programming.

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<?php

//Require config.php file to connect with mysql server and the db.
require_once('config.php');

//Calling PHasher class file.
include_once('phasher/phasher.class.php');
$I = PHasher::Instance();

$testImage = "./avatar/4.jpg";

$hash = $I->FastHashImage($testImage);
$hex = $I->HashAsString($hash);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `fid`,`hash` FROM `images`");

while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['hash'] == $hex){
        //echo $row['hash'];
        $fid = $row['fid'];
        echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$fid/picture?type=large'></a>";
    }
}
```